Why is the soil in my yard moist after a water main repair?
We recently had a water main break repaired because we noticed seeping water coming up from out lawn. The repair occurred the day before yesterday. All water was turned back on. Yesterday upon going out the throw out my trash, I noticed that in the area where the repair was is mostly dry, however there is an area of the soil that appears to be moist. I felt the soil and it definitely is moist. I further noticed that when pushing down on the soil with my hand, the soil started to sink in slightly. Could this mean that the repair might have been unsuccessful and the water main break is still leaking?
This picture is from a week after the water main break repair was made:


Possible, but more likely the ground has not dry out yet.  Give it a few days and see.  If fixed and no rain, then it should get dryer.

Could this mean that the repair might have been unsuccessful and the water main break is still leaking? ... the answer can never be a no

If your soil has high clay content, it will hold water longer than you'd expect.

I just checked the soil for clay content and yes it does have high clay content. Now I understand why it was still moist. Thank u.

It hasn't rained in weeks. It did not rain prior to the repair nor in the days that followed. We haven't watered the grass either because the soil was too damp at the time the repair was made as well as days following the repair. Yet in the photo one can see how the soil is dry over most of the repair site, however there are still moist patches in the bottom corners of the photo. This photo was taken a week after repairs.

The disrupted soil often dries faster than the surrounding area, but keep an eye on it. If you know where the line runs, and you're sure the damp spot is over top of the line, keep two eyes on it.
If the line has lots of joints, and a leaking joint was repaired without replacing the whole line, its possible another joint failed or was missed because the larger leak drew attention. Remember the whole thing was installed at once, so the pipe and joints are the same age and may start to fail for the same reason -- the better the original work, the more likely this will happen.

Well it's been almost a week since the repair was made and the soil still appears damp. I checked again and yes the soil is still moist in said area.
